# Ignoring preexisting data in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark stream that process files in an S3 prefix. The issue is that there are many TBs of data already in this prefix, meaning the EMR cluster underneath Spark is getting throttled trying to process it when the stream is turned on.

What I want is to ignore all files before a certain date, and then have the stream run normally. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: Seems an odd use case. Why would this be so out of interest?

Comment: @thebluephantom We're replacing an existing process that has already ingested all of the data in the bucket. So we're only concerned with new data when cutting over to Spark structured streaming.

Comment: Gotcha. Sort of handy to mention. Success. We r doing things with cdc and after initial load we check scn num from oracle. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found what I need.

```scala
val df=spark.readStream
  .schema(testSchema)
  .option(“maxFileAge”, “1”)
  .parquet(“s3://bucket/prefix”)
```

This ignores everything older than a week.